# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' [AWS Glue]

Tags: python, psycopg2, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue where I'm trying to use psycopg2 in a pyspark script. Since glue does not support psycopg2 in its execution environment, I am passing it in `--additional-python-moodules`. Which is a way of installing additional Python modules in aws glue.

After following the steps mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html). I am getting an error while running the job which says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'`

[image]

Here are the job parameters are being passed during the execution.

[image]

Solutions I have already tried:

1. Using psycopg2-binary
2. Passing a zip/whl file in --additional-python-modules
3. Changing glue version to 2.0 and 3.0

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html), the libraries not supported by glue needs to be present in S3 path first i.e. .whl or .zip file can be uploaded in S3 and then path needs to be passed in `--additional-python-modules` like `s3://<bucket-name>/<path-to-whl-zip-file>`

From documentation: `Dependencies must be hosted in Amazon S3 and the argument value should be a comma delimited list of Amazon S3 paths with no spaces.`

As per the job parameters passed by you it just mentions `psycopg2-binary` which isn't really installing any python package and hence you are getting the error.

Hope it helps.